# Text overflow issue on mobile, resizes instead of overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue that I'm trying to wrap my head around.

I first found this issue on the **device toolbar** in the **Google Chrome DevTools**, but I have also been able to replicate this behaviour on my **android phone**.

The code below works in a regular screen as I resize the browser window, but in the device toolbar when I resize the screen the text is resized to fit as if it were an image with **max-width** set instead of a text block with **hidden overflow**.

Can someone enlighten me on why this happens? (and perhaps how to fix)

```
<div>
<strong>This strong element seems to really add something.</strong> Weirly enough<br>
<strong>Weirdest part:</strong> Things change when I remove this part &lt;and the lt gt&gt;
</div>

<p>
This paragraph seems to work completely as intended. Which makes sense because it is a plain boii.
</p>

<a href="#">This test link is working as expected.</a>
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 21px; font-size: 14px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">This text get way too small in chrome devtools mobile preview, which is weird because I'd expect ellipsis</span>
```

Expected behavior:

[image: Expected behavior]

device tool behavior:

[image: Expected behavior]
<sub>(source: [fam-teunissen.nl](https://sander.fam-teunissen.nl/images/device_tool.PNG))</sub>

EDIT:
Added screenshots + corrected div start tag not showing up because of incorrect formatting

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot?

Comment: It work as expected on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/smkzqvh1/3/. Please notice that you have a `</div>` tag in your code that is not open. Just remove it.

Comment: the starting div tag was not showing because I formatted the code block incorrectly.
Also: I added screenshots to clarify